# Nginx redirect with rewrite and regex

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect

I need to set the following configutation in Nginx:

http://my.server.com/login.aspx?param1=value1 --> http://any.other.server/path/page?param2=value1

I've tried using these snippets:

```
location ^(/login\.aspx\?param1=)(\w+) {
    proxy_pass http://any.other.server/path/page?param2=$2
}

location ^(/login\.aspx\?param1=)(\w+) {
    return http://any.other.server/path/page?param2=$2
}
```

I've tried also other configurations using `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`, `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`, but I'm still unable.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

location only adpate to path , cannt load request param.
return need a http code.

```
 location ~ ^/login\.aspx {
    return 301 http://any.other.server/path/page?param2=$arg_param1;
  }
```